# how to connect to oracle database from snowflake?

Tags: oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have to pull some data from oracle and update the data in snowflake. And ofcourse the size of the data is 5gb. 
Is there any procedure to connect to oracle database from snowflake? OR
Do I need to connect them using a programming language as python?

Comment: 5GB is tiny, just down load the data to your PC then upload to Snowfalke. Unless you mistyped and meant 5TB. Which I'd still just download..

Comment: downloading of 5gb data to pc is taking lot of time I would say 18hours. and this task has to be done daily.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to unload the data from Oracle and load into Snowflake, as there are no "direct connect" options I've ever heard about.

I'd use SQL*Loader to unload, push the files to AWS S3 (or your cloud vendor's storage), and issue Snowflake COPY INTO TABLE commands, it should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: But we are not completely moving out the data from oracle. Table in oracle gets updated daily and i have to replicate that updated into snowflake daily. So what can be good procedure.

Comment: You update your question then,. because you have asked about a one off data pull, verse a data sync. We have tools that pull updated rows and writes those to S3 and then tell snowflake to load those files, and for some tables we just pull the whole table each 8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use python programming to extract and load data from oracle to snowflake. Since your oracle table is being updated daily write python program to generate merge statement dynamically to load your incremental data from oracle to snowflake.

- Snowflake supports Java script based stored procedure so you can use stored procedure to generate merge statement dynamically by passing table name as parameter and you can call it via python.
- Initial load from oracle to snowflake may take time as you have 5GB data from your source system.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent to Oracle database links in Snowflake. You would need an external process to move the data from Oracle to S3. Then you can configure a Snowpipe task to load from S3 into Snowflake. See [Loading Continuously Using Snowpipe](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe.html) for more information.